# Return formatted string as ref to bytes

Tags: rust, ownership

I have the following struct:

```rust
struct CompareUrl {
    repo: String,
    left: String,
    right: String,
}
```

And I want this struct to return itself in bytes.

```rust
impl CompareUrl {
    pub fn as_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        format!(
            "https://github.com/{}/compare/{}...{}",
            self.repo,
            self.left,
            self.right
        ).as_bytes()
    }
}
```

But it complains about ownership:

```
cannot return reference to temporary value
returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

It seems that it works for `(&str).as_bytes()`, but not for `(String).as_bytes()`. My attempt was to solve this like that:

```rust
impl CompareUrl {
    pub fn as_bytes(&self) -> &[u8] {
        format!(
            "https://github.com/{}/compare/{}...{}",
            self.repo,
            self.left,
            self.right
        ).as_str().as_bytes()
    }
}
```

But it raises the same error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a reference to a value owned by the function, like the `String` the `format!` macro produces, because it gets dropped when the function returns and the reference would be invalid. Use the `into_bytes` method to turn your `String` into an owned `Vec` of bytes instead:

```
impl CompareUrl {
    pub fn as_bytes(&self) -> Vec<u8> {
        format!(
            "https://github.com/{}/compare/{}...{}",
            self.repo,
            self.left,
            self.right
        ).into_bytes()
    }
}
```